# Two Sonata Admin Panel Bundles in one Symfony application

Tags: symfony, sonata, symfony-2.8

Is it possible to have two Sonata Admin Panel Bundles in one Symfony application? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can only add one bundle in app. What about making one general project and than add 2 sf apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As KondukterCRO mentioned, **it is possible to have only one Sonata Admin** installation per Symfony project.

However, if you need, you can have:

- **Two dashboards**, for example have one [native dashboard](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/reference/dashboard.html) and for second dashboard - make a custom action + template
- **Two sets of entities** with different access rights. Alhthough all Sonata Admin pages will have one comon prefix - you still can separate access rights to Sonata Admin pages with simple rules in security.yml >> access_control section, or more complex rules - in every admin class, in method ::isGranted()

Comment: Just to add few lines to your good approach. 
Make one general sf project and for example in one bundle implement sonata and in another bundle run entire new sf app with new sonata. It's little bit too much work to configure everything to work but, ...
Another thing, maybe you could add multiple roles and have one admin area with one sonata and based on role grant permissions.